# MS Excel - convert randomly formatted cells into hh:mm:ss time format

Tags: excel, time

i have a problem worth thousands lines.. i have a column which suppose to represent track time:

```
13:43
00:00:59
14:14
14:28
14:49
15:13
15:34
15:38
16:08
16:18
16:48
17:24
18:37
18:39
18:59
19:24
0:24:17
00:01:15
00:01:22
00:01:26
00:01:42
0:34:37
1.45
1.47
1.47
1.47
1.48
1.48
```

i.e. while looking to user ok - 13:43 is actually 13 hours 43 mins 00 sec
while there are correctly formatted time `00:00:59` and some are just decimal numbers!
they all were suppose to be mm:ss format, but now i'm transferring this spreadsheet into database - i will obviously have incorrect time formats all over...

any easy/not so easy way to normalise them all?

Comment: what would the decimal values represent?  1.45 would be 1.45 minutes,  1 minute 45 seconds, or something else?

Comment: it would be 1 min and 45 secs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
=IF(LEFT(CELL("format",A1),1)="D",TEXT(A1,"hh:mm:ss"),IF(ISERR(TIMEVALUE(A1)),TEXT(TIMEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",":")),"hh:mm:ss"),TEXT(TIMEVALUE(A1),"hh:mm:ss")))
```

Update:
As per last comment.  Updated formula to treat hh:mm as mm:ss.  So this at least will work for all except the 13:43 one, which is genuinely hh:mm

```
=IF(CELL("format",A1)="D9",TEXT(TIMEVALUE("00:"&TEXT(A1,"hh:mm")),"hh:mm:ss"),IF(LEFT(CELL("format",A1),1)="D",TEXT(A1,"hh:mm:ss"),IF(ISERR(TIMEVALUE(A1)),TEXT(TIMEVALUE("00:"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",":")),"hh:mm:ss"),TEXT(TIMEVALUE(A1),"hh:mm:ss"))))
```

Comment: i will try this tomorrow at work. thanks. but which part converts i.e 18:37 (excel thinks 18 hours 37 mins) into 00:18:37?

Comment: Oh! I thought that was 18 hrs as well. I'm a bit surprised your users are recording to the accuracy of 37 seconds!!  You stated that your first record 13:43 was 13 hrs 43 mins, considering there isn't any difference between that and 18:37, there isn't much you can do.

Comment: see new formula added to my answer above.  This will treat all hh:mm as if they were mm:ss

Comment: it did work on everything apart from: visually 02:51 => excel reads 02:51:00 => converted to 02:51:00, while it should be 00:02:51 - to those i applied =TEXT(TIMEVALUE("00:"&TEXT(G2,"hh:mm")),"hh:mm:ss") and all fine now!!! thanks a lot!